# How to remove the combobox after an item is picked

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to destroy a combobox right after the user picks an item that is not the default one ("Please select an option") which is at index 0.

Here's the code:

```
private void btn_options_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Options_DropDown = new ComboBox();

        //Build a list
        var dataSource = new List<Options_Items>();            
        dataSource.Add(new Options_Items() { Commentmethod = "Please select an option." });
        dataSource.Add(new Options_Items() { Commentmethod = "Override selected file." });
        dataSource.Add(new Options_Items() { Commentmethod = "Create a copy of the selected file at selected location."});
        dataSource.Add(new Options_Items() { Commentmethod = "Copy the commented version to clipboard."});

        //Setup data binding
        Options_DropDown.DataSource = dataSource;
        Options_DropDown.DisplayMember = "Commentmethod";

        // make it readonly
        Options_DropDown.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

        Options_DropDown.SetBounds(401, 290, 171, 23);

        if (Options_DropDown.SelectedIndex != 0) //this if is not working the way I want it to
        {
            Controls.Remove(Options_DropDown);
        }

        this.Controls.Add(Options_DropDown);
    }
```

And then the class to add the items

```
public class Options_Items
    {
        public string Commentmethod { get; set; }
    }
```

Extra info: I click a button that makes the combobox appear, after which I select an item and the combobox gets deleted.

Comment: Please define "destroy". Do you mean hide or disable? We can remove it from the UI, but destroying it might cause all kinds of issues down the line. But generally it is a bad-ish idea to disable a selection area after selection.

Comment: Hiding it would also work. I just don't want it to be on the screen after I select something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure which Display Technology you are using, but both WinForms and WPF/UWP GUI classes have the options to set any element to Invisible, Disable them or even remove it from the UI outright. However with removing you must really be careful to maintain a reference, as otherwise, it might get Garbage Collected. Disable or Invisible sounds slightly better.

However, the whole idea of removing a UI element after a selection (or at all) is weird, to say the least. I only know joke programs to ever do that.

What if the user wants to correct his input later? Usually, if you do not want something to be shown anymore, you put it into a different Register Card/Page/another way to split the UI into separate segments. Then the user can choose to not see it anymore, but also choose to return.

Comment: First time developing an application so the advice you gave me helps a lot. The idea of this combobox is to pick an option, if you pick the wrong thing you can click a button again and the combobox will reapear.

Comment: @IvailoHristov: Could you be a bit more specific? What is being selected? How does the selection affect the other parts of the UI? How does it affect programm flow?